# C# using object properties after finding which type

Tags: c#, object

Let's say I have an array of objects with different specific generic types like int, string, datetime and etc

How can I after finding out which type is the object (with `typeOf`) can use the functions on that object ?

For example

I got `Object []` a

and after checking it out I found that `a[0]` is a `DateTime` and i want to use it `ToShortDateString` property

how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
object[] a;

//  ...

if (a[0] is DateTime)
{
   ((DateTime)a[0]).ToShortDateString();
}
```